# Idea of making Router managment System with Flutter

Tags: flutter, wifi, router, dio

I'm working on a Flutter app to manage wifi router settings, and I need guidance on how can i make it. The goal is to establish a connection and perform tasks like logging in, fetching the informatoin of it, or make edits of in the router page,.... etc. i know that each model in router has a different way to connect with but i need only the way on my router
how can i connect to my router with credentails of it through my app ( simple ui is just the ip,username, password)?

i tried to use dio package and make a successfull got to the router page with dio package but trying to connect to my router through post method and it doesn't work at all